# What does the `@` mean in key-shortcuts?

Tags: key-bindings

For beginners it is sometimes hard to understand the description of key-shortcuts.

I found a `@` sign in this context; e.g. `C-c @ C-f`
What does it mean?

More examples here:

https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ide.html#folding

**EDIT**: When I literally type this I got `C-c @ C-f is undefined`

**EDIT2**: And I am quit sure that elpy itself is active because a `*.py` file is opened and all the other elpy magic (syntax checks etc) are working well.

Comment: I don't use elpy, but I guess it just means to literally type an `@`

Comment: Is elpy active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` symbol doesn't have a special meaning in a keybinding, it represents the symbol `@` (i.e., Shift+2 on US keyboards). `C-c @ C-f` is a keybinding defined by `hs-minor-mode`, which `elpy` has apparently extended. You should be able to use it after calling `M-x hs-minor-mode`.